# how get all elements of array in deserialize json c#?

Tags: c#, json, jsonserializer

In C #, I have 5-6 days and I wanted to try to use the api one site. 
I have deserialize JSON and here is the format

> [
>     {
>       "uid": 1476402,
>       "first_name": "**",
>       "last_name": "**",
>       "domain": "sandrische",
>       "online": 1,
>       "user_id": 1476402
>     },
>     {
>       "uid": 3813182,
>       "first_name": "**",
>       "last_name": "**",
>       "domain": "id3813182",
>       "online": 0,
>       "user_id": 3813182
>     },
>     {
>       "uid": 12789624,
>       "first_name": "**",
>       "last_name": "**",
>       "domain": "id12789624",
>       "online": 0,
>       "user_id": 12789624
>     }]

there is a class

```
 public class vkResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "uid")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "photo_50")]
    public Uri PhotoUri { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "online")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(BoolConverter))]
    public bool IsOnline { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lists")]
    public List<int> Lists { get; set; }

}


public class BoolConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((bool)value) ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return reader.Value.ToString() == "1";
    }
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(bool);
    }
}
```

I want to get id

```
 var req = new HttpRequest();
        string resp = req.Get("https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_ids=1&fields=domain&access_token=" + GetToken()).ToString();
       JObject o = JObject.Parse(resp);
        JArray array = (JArray)o["response"];
        vkResponse v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<vkResponse>(array.First().ToString());

        richTextBox1.Text = v.Id.ToString();
```

But I get only the first ID, how to get all ID?
I think that the problem in this `array.First().ToString()` ? Please help or give an example.

Comment: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'WindowsFormsApplication30.vkResponse' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection

Comment: If you're using this through an asp.net web-api controller you can simply take this as an argument to the action and the serializer should sort it for you automatically. Meaning void myaction([FromBody] vkResponse[] responses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is an array of `vkResponse` classes, so you could deserialize it as a [c# array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7fscd0.aspx):

```
vkResponse[] vkResponses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<vkResponse[]>(array.ToString());
```

Once you have the array you can loop through and access the IDs of each element.

> Pleaase , give me example how loop through and access the IDs of each elemen

OK, here's a way to do it using elementary c# looping constructs and arrays:

```
    vkResponse[] vkResponses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<vkResponse[]>(array.ToString());
    if (vkResponses == null)
        throw new JsonException();
    int [] ids = new int[vkResponses.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < vkResponses.Length; i++)
    {
        ids[i] = vkResponses[i].Id;
    }
```

If you want to show the IDs as a comma-separated sequence of integers in the rich text box, you use the following method to generate the string:

```
    public static string ExtractVkResponseIds(string vkResponseJson)
    {
        vkResponse[] vkResponses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<vkResponse[]>(vkResponseJson);
        if (vkResponses == null)
            throw new JsonException();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Format the ids as a comma separated string.
        foreach (var response in vkResponses)
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
                sb.Append(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator);
            sb.Append(response.Id.ToString());
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

and call it like:

```
    var req = new HttpRequest();
    string resp = req.Get("https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_ids=1&fields=domain&access_token=" + GetToken()).ToString();
    JObject o = JObject.Parse(resp);
    JArray array = (JArray)o["response"];
    string ids = ExtractVkResponseIds(array.ToString());
    richTextBox1.Text = ids;
```

I used the localized [ListSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.listseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), by the way, which might not be a comma in your language.  You can change it to a literal comma if you want.

Your sample Json string is missing a closing bracket ("]"), by the way.

Comment: Pleaase , give me example how  loop through and access the IDs of each elemen , i am stupid rus guy ((99

Comment: Thank you very much :) 
And how it all lead to the textbox?)

Comment: if using `richTextBox1.Text = vkResponses[i].Id.ToString();` ,the outputs one Id ((

Comment: @voodooSHA A - what do you want to show the user in the text box when multiple objects are returned?  Each Id on a separate line?  Each Id separated by a comma?  Or what?

Comment: It does not matter, separated by commas or on a new line, I want to start just polucht all Ids, rather than one.

Comment: @voodooSHA A - OK, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

```
var v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<vkResponse>>(array.ToString());

var userids = v.Select(x=>x.id);
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WindowsFormsApplication30.vkResponse>' to 'WindowsFormsApplication30.vkResponse'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\Pc\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication30\WindowsFormsApplication30\Form1.cs 31 28 WindowsFormsApplication30

Comment: Thx. But how to access the ID property?

Comment: If i am use `var userid = v.First().Id;` still get first ID , but i want get all Id's

Comment: Yes, can you check now?

Comment: `var v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<vkResponse>>(array.ToString());
            var userids = v.Select(x => x.Id);
            richTextBox1.Text = userids.ToString();` turned `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[WindowsFormsApplication30.vkResponse,System.Int32]`